# C64, basic v2, DATA strange behavior

Tags: commodore-64, basic

I have the following code line:

```
 0DATA"-+-+-"
```

Here "`\`" and "`/`" are the ASC codes 205 and 206.

I get a syntax error:

```
?SYNTAX  ERROR IN 0
READY.
```

As I can remember, there was same special in the handling of the special terminal-controlling characters in strings. For example, a reverse ❤ has deleted the screen on print, but it behaved normally in the source code.

Any idea, what could be the reason?

[image]

---

*Extension: my tests show it happens with all strings, not only for these. I use vice.*

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you add a screenshot showing everything you did?

Comment: @RossRidge Tyvm! I added the screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot's line 0 is different from your transcribed line 0..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem may be with your READ statement, not the DATA statement.  If you have string data, make sure you read into a string variable like so:

```
10 READ X$
```

If you try to read string data into a numeric variable you will get a syntax error reported on the DATA line, even though it was the READ that triggered it.  So this would give you an error:

```
0 DATA "A"
10 READ X
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with the flowing line:

```
2 READS:X=1024:FORY=1TOLEN(S):A=ASC(MID$(S,Y,1)):POKEX,A:X=X-165+A*2:NEXT
```

String variables in BASIC need to suffixes with a dollar sign `$`. So all your uses of the variable `S` should be `S$`:

```
2 READS$:X=1024:FORY=1TOLEN(S$):A=ASC(MID$(S$,Y,1)):POKEX,A:X=X-165+A*2:NEXT
```